# Getting a SAML assertion after creating a session via API

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

Related to [Accessing Third Party Apps After Creating A Session Via API Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728640/accessing-third-party-apps-after-creating-a-session-via-api-token/42729609) and to [AWS API credentials with OneLogin SAML and MFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336144/aws-api-credentials-with-onelogin-saml-and-mfa)

Since AWS `assumeRoleWithSAML` temporary security credentials are only valid for one hour and we have a few different roles to assume it would be very annoying for the user to enter the username/password everytime he needs to switch the role or get new credentials because of the short validity. It's totally odd to the web base OneLogin usage, where he is logged in once for the whole day or even week (depending on the policy).

I know how to get a session via API. At least this would reduce the times the user needs to enters username/password to two times. One time in the web, one time on the CLI.

But is there any way to use this session token to generate a SAML assertion via API with this session token instead of submitting username/password to the API endpoint?
I don't want so store the users credentials locally for this. And with MFA enabled this wouldn't work in a seamless way.

Answer (score 1):

While being able to generate a SAML assertion for any user (without the need for MFA and a user/pass) seems like a good workaround, this is unfortunately fraught with security perils.

An API that bypasses the usual authentication effectively gives that endpoint the ability to assume any user in AWS. The "assume user" privilege is locked down pretty tightly in OneLogin, and is not the sort of thing that's given out lightly.

Basically, an API to do this seems dangerous from a security perspective. This might be something we'd consider as part of an oAuth flow (or OpenID Connect resource endpoint) but that'll take some more thinking on our part before we'd implement it.

The only compromise solution I can think of that could be implemented today would be to temporarily cache the users' credentials for a longer period of time in your code. This way they could be reused to generate new SAML assertions for a longer period of time, but would effectively be thrown away after (say) eight hours.

This wouldn't allow for MFA on an app policy, but we are building out the ability to request and verify MFA via API (coming soon) so you could implement MFA in your app (independent of any app policy) once this becomes available.

Obviously the ideal solution would be for AWS to let users' configure the session length, but so far they've been unwilling to allow this.